# How to read and modify url with UI Vision 2019 (aka Selenium IDE++)

Tags: selenium, url, kantu

I'm using UI Vision 2019 (aka Selenium IDE++) for testing purposes. I have to read and modify url in one of my test cases. How can I do that?

I've already gone through a lot of research on internet.

Answer (score 0):

executeScript | return document.URL |  a or <any variable
command       | firts parameter     | second parameter

now your current url will stor in variable in this case is a
value of a is equal to curent url so you can use this variable like ${a}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

You can go to another URL using the command "open". If you wanna store a url from some object you can use "storeAttribute"

You can find loads of information and examples of this commands here:

[open](https://ui.vision/rpa/docs/selenium-ide/open)

[storeAttribute](https://ui.vision/rpa/docs/selenium-ide/storeattribute)

Comment: Provide the pertinent information from these links/